# Publishing a script error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When trying to publish a script I get this error

> API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace SDK enabled.

**Update** I should of place more details about my issues. But it's a simple script to clear out columns in Google Sheets.

```
function doTest() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Store #1").getRange('E7:E215').setValue('');
```

Comment: Publish a script where? How? You should probably also include the actual script (preferably a [minimal version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it).

Comment: So, is this an android question? I recommend using more specific tags to catch the attention of people who can help you.

Comment: Also, in addition to Dukeling's link, you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should probably enable the "Google Apps Marketplace SDK".

Comment: It's a script for Google Sheets. All I'm doing is to clearing out Columns. function doTest() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Store #1").getRange('E7:E215').setValue('');

Answer (score 0):

While publishing the script, you should get the spreadsheet using url of the spreadsheet instead of getActiveSpreadsheet. Try below code

```
function doTest() { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LCX3gHsv2vJgobf*****-*********HHA");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Store #1");
    sheet.getRange('E7:E215').setValue('');
}
```

You can create new Menu on the toolbar with following code. When user clicks the menu item, your script (doTest function) will be executed. You can refer this documentation for more details.

```
function onOpen() {
    var menuEntries = [
       {name: 'Click me', functionName: 'doTest'},
    ];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.addMenu('New Menu', menuEntries);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: One more question. Do I need to add another line so it has an option to run it. It go published, but I add it to the sheet, the add-on has only a help option and no way to run it.